# Composer: Can only install one of: minishlink/web-push[v4.0.0, dev-master]

Tags: php, composer-php, installation, web-push

I'm trying install web-push (https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php) in Ubuntu 14 but with a execute composer require minishlink/web-push I get the next error:

```
Problem 1:
 - Can only install one of: minishlink/web-psuh[v4.0.0, dev-master].
 - Can only install one of: minishlink/web-psuh[v4.0.1, dev-master].
 - Can only install one of: minishlink/web-psuh[v4.0.2, dev-master].
 - Installation request for minishlink/web-push dev-master -> Satisfiable by minishlink/web-push[dev-master].
 - Installation request for minishlink/web-push ^4.0 -> satisfiable by minishlink/web-push[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2].
```

Composer.json

```
    {
  "name": "minishlink/web-push",
  "type": "library",
  "description": "Web Push library for PHP",
  "keywords": ["push", "notifications", "web", "WebPush", "Push API"],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Louis Lagrange",
      "email": "lagrange.louis@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/Minishlink"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "minishlink/web-push": "^4.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to share your `composer.json` and full output of `composer require` call.

Comment: added composer.json

Comment: You package is named that same as your dependency (`minishlink/web-push`). What you're trying to do?

Comment: If you want to install `minishlink/web-push` aa a dependency, you should not edit its `composer.json`. You should have your own `composer.json` in your project.